# Can someone help me ordering this list?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am not the best programmer, so need some help to order this list. I had a few stabs at it, but still getting some cases which are wrong.

Essentially the list is the following:

```
#, ID, PreceedingID
A, 1 ,     0
B, 2 ,     3
C, 3 ,     1   
D, 4 ,     2
```

I want to order it so that the list follows the preceeding id. The first item will always have the preceeding ID of 0.

```
#, ID, PreceedingID
A, 1 ,     0
C, 3 ,     1
B, 2 ,     3   
D, 4 ,     2
```

Do you think you can help?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you representing this list? An Object, a database?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code? Which part is hard for you?

Comment: I don't see the ordering... "follows the preceeding id"...but the list you have is 0, 1, 3, 2.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @chris It's actually a List of controls that I have on a page. So you can assume something like the following List<ControlData> controls, and the properties within each item are id and preceeding ID

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
var data = new[] {
    new Row{ Name = "A", ID = 1, PreceedingID = 0},
    new Row{ Name = "B", ID = 2, PreceedingID = 3},
    new Row{ Name = "C", ID = 3, PreceedingID = 1},
    new Row{ Name = "D", ID = 4, PreceedingID = 2},
};
var byLastId = data.ToDictionary(x => x.PreceedingID);

var newList = new List<Row>(data.Length);
int lastId = 0;
Row next;
while (byLastId.TryGetValue(lastId, out next))
{
    byLastId.Remove(lastId); // removal avoids infinite loops
    newList.Add(next);
    lastId = next.ID;
}
```

After this, `newList` has the data in the desired order.

In the above, `Row` is:

```
class Row
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PreceedingID { get; set; }
}
```

But obviously substitute for your own type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example dictionary to sort it:

```
Dictionary<..> d = new Dictionary<..>()
foreach(var el in list){
    d[el.PreceedingID] = el; //put data to dict by PreecedingID
}
List<..> result = new List<..>();
int prec = 0; //get first ID
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i){
    var actEl = d[prec]; //get next element
    prec = actEl.ID; //change prec id
    result.Add(actEl); //put element into result list
}
```